# WEB API HTTP Header

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, sapui5

I have a problem with my WebAPI. I build a ODATA Web API with C#.
It works fine, but not in my SAPUI5 application.

I think the problem is, that the header that I created is not separated by semicolon so the SAPUI5 application can't interpret it correkt.

```
mPredefinedRequestHeaders: {Accept: "application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;IEEE754Compatible=true", OData-MaxVersion: "4.0", OData-Version: "4.0", X-CSRF-Token: "Fetch"}
```

The error is that the Odata-Version is null.

I add the Header in c# with the following code:

```
// res.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
res.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-type,odata-maxversion,odata-version,x-csrf-token");
// res.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS");
res.AppendHeader("OData-Version ", "4.0");
res.AppendHeader("Content-Type:", "application/json; odata.metadata=minimal");
res.AppendHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
```

Can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to communicate with SAPUI5 using OData v4. The implementation of this version in SAPUI5 is not production ready. See this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52876846/430742